# p:layout and p:layoutUnit ignore the style

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

My question is quite simple. I'm using PrimeFaces 4.0 and the layout component.

The problem comes, when I try to adjust its CSS.
I want to set its background to none, I tried the classic `style="background: none !important` but it ignores me, then I inspect the element in Google Chrome and saw that the `.ui-widget-content` style was the one which I wanted to hide then I try this:

```
<p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:1000px; .ui-widget-content {background: none !important;}">
<p:layoutUnit position="west" size="620" minSize="40" style=".ui-widget-content {background: none !important;}">
```

But it still doesn't work. Plus, in my css theme I have:

```css
body .ui-widget-content {

    border-style: hidden;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 0px;
    color: #4f4f4f;
}
```

If I add the background: none in there it does work, but screw up the theme of my whole application.
Is there a way to hide the background for that single widget-content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't fiddle around with `style` attribute. Just give it a class which you declare in a CSS file.

```
<p:layout styleClass="backgroundless">
```

```css
.ui-layout-container.backgroundless .ui-widget-content {
    background: none;
}
```

#### See also:

- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)
- [CSS beginner tutorial](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. That was exactly what I needed. I'm gonna check the css tutorial when I have a time, thanks again man!